# Why I am getting an empty values from a Redux Form in reactJs?

Tags: reactjs, react-redux, redux-form

I don't understand why I am getting an empty values when I click on the submit button. I get: `You have submitted: {}`. The problem is same when I click on `Reset data`-button. According to what I understood the result should be `{"firmName":"test"`}. I can't get it to work. Any help or suggestions is very appreciate.

```
class FirmDataTab extends Component {

    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            firmName: 'test'
        };
        this.reset = this.reset.bind(this);
    }

    reset() {
        this.setState = {
            firmName: ''
        };
    }

    render() {
        const { handleSubmit } = this.props;
        return(
            <form onSubmit={ handleSubmit }>
                <div className="jumbotron">
                    <div>
                        <label>Firm name</label>
                        <div style={{marginTop: -22, marginLeft: 80}}>
                            <input
                                name="firmnname"
                                type="text"
                                defaultValue={this.state.firmName} />
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div>
                        <FormGroup>
                            <Col smOffset={2} sm={10}>
                                <button
                                    type="submit"
                                    className="btn btn-info" style={{marginLeft: -40, marginRight: 20, marginTop: 10}}> Submit </button>
                                <button onClick={this.reset}> Reset data </button>
                            </Col>
                        </FormGroup>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </form>

        );
    }
}

FirmDataTab .propTypes = {
    handleSubmit: PropTypes.func.isRequired
};

export default reduxForm({
    form: 'TestForm'   

})(FirmDataTab);
```

Answer (score 0):

`defaultValue` prop doesn't reflect the state change. You should use `value` prop instead. Check [the doc](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/uncontrolled-components.html#default-values) for more detail.

Comment: `@Phi Nguyen` I changed to `value` and still the same problem. In addition i get: `Failed form propType: You provided a `value` prop to a form field without an `onChange` handler. This will render a read-only field.If the field should be mutable use `defaultValue`. Otherwise, set either `onChange` or `readOnly`. Check the render method of `FirmDataTab`.

Comment: @carl You should create an event handler when value of the input is changed. Check this example. https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/lifting-state-up.html

Answer (score 0):

The first mistake you have made here is the local state management. With redux forms you need to connect the form with the global application state. You can't use local setState any more.

Here is the working solution. At the time of submit I have logged the input values. You may call your action creator with the same values to save the data into the back end. Do the same for reset and other scenarios as well. I have commented them here.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { Field, reduxForm, formValueSelector } from 'redux-form';

class UserNameNew extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
    }

    onSubmit(values) {
      console.log(values);
      // Call the action creator which is responsible for saving data here.
    }

    reset() {
      // call the action creator to reset the state here.
    }

    render() {
        const { handleSubmit } = this.props;
        return(
            <form onSubmit={ handleSubmit(this.onSubmit.bind(this)) }>
                <div>
                    <div>
                        <label>First Name</label>
                        <div style={{marginTop: -22, marginLeft: 80}}>
                            <Field name="firstName" component="input" type="text" />
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div>
                      <button type="submit" className="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </form>

        );
    }
}

export default reduxForm({
    form: 'UserNameForm'

})(UserNameNew);
```

Hope this helps. Happy coding !